# Does race affect movement speed?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm finding conflicting sources.

**Race does affect movement speed**

1. [From uesp](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Races#Notes):

   > The movement speed of each race is dependent on its height (...)
2. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aiel3MHpFhU) showing a test.
3. Some guy on the bethesda forums [did a test](http://forums.bethsoft.com/topic/1286166-hidden-stat-differences-based-on-race-selection/?p=19410120):

   > Wood Elf (scale = 0.98) : 47.3 seconds to run the track.
   >
   > Imperial (scale = 1.00) : 46.35 seconds to run the track.
   >
   > Nord (scale = 1.03) : 45 seconds to run the track.
   >
   > High Elf (scale = 1.08) : 42.9 seconds to run the track.

**Race does NOT affect movement speed**

4. [From elderscrolls.wikia](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Races_(Skyrim)#Stats_affected_by_character_size):

   > Without console command modification, the damage output, damage resistance, jump height, run speed, weapon reach, etc., for all races remains at a scale of 1.00, with the race specific scales being purely cosmetic only (...)

I was only able to find tests showing that race does affect movement speed, so is this the correct answer?

Comment: UESP has proof.  Of course that's the correct one.  You'll have to find proof to refut e it.

Answer (score 1):

UESP is usually correct, and it has proof, so I see no reason to doubt it.

Answer (score -1):

So... this is kinda funny.  Both of these are correct at the same time.

The wiki is correct because the character speed setting is unchanged based on race.

But.

The actual speed is different as measured because of one odd fact in the engine:  Taller characters move faster.

As this post shows, the character races effective speed varies because each race has a slightly different height.

https://www.reddit.com/r/skyrim/comments/mumu5/did_you_know_that_your_character_height_affects/

Now... if you found that entertaining, perhaps this will be even more so:

Cicero moves faster at different points in the plot line.

As it turns out, for complicated reasons, there isn't one Cicero... there are three.  If I recall correctly, two of them are of shorter size, and one is taller.

So, if you can outrun him... be careful, because later, he might outrun you.  :-)

https://www.reddit.com/r/skyrim/comments/1fk1o0/height_problems/

Comment: That speed is linked to height is already mentioned in the question.